# page $102$ from Ahlfors.

Tags: complex-analysis

He talks about a function $f(a)$ for which all the derivatives vanish. He shows inside a circle within our domain $\Omega$, for any circle $C$ we take, there $f$ is identicaly zero.

Then he shows that $f$ is identically zero in $\Omega$. Let $E_1$ be the set where $f$ and all its derivatives vanish, and $E_2$ be the set on which the function or one of the derivatives is nonzero. Then $E_1$ is open because for any $x\in E_1$, we can just get a circle within which the function vanish. Now $E_2$ is also open, and the reason he gives is because the function and all derivatives are continuous. Im not sure why $E_2$ is open.  $f$ is analytic hence continuous, so around any point $x\in E_2$, we have a smaller ball within which $f$ is continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_0\in E_2$,say $f^{(n)}(x_0)\ne 0$. As $f^{(n)}$ is continuous, the set $\{\,x\in \Omega \mid f^{(n)}(x)\ne 0\,\}$ is open (and contains $x_0$).